# Integrate with Google button - what happens on redirection?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

I'm in charge of migrating a listing from the old Google Enterprise Marketplace to the new version, changing the Auth scheme as well.

I get the new OAuth2 **authentication** scheme, it is implemented.

However, I have a question regarding the "Integrate with Google" button, what should happen when the user is redirected to the **Universal Navigation Extension** URL? My guess is that we ought to make that URL a call to the SignIn using google with the domain already filled, is that the process?
If so, then the Integrate with Google is a process mostly on Google side, that allows one to subsequently get a valid email and response when a user tries to sign in with google. Is that the case?

Could somebody provide an example flow for the "Integrate with Google" button?

Comment: The integrate with Google makes it possible for an admin to install you app from different places (e.g. from your website) instead from Google Marketplace in their domain. https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/button   After the installation the users can access your app (probably using the Universal Navigation Extension), and then you will go through the OAuth 2 flow in order to authenticate them. https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing#about_app_extensions   let me know if its not clear.

Comment: All you said was clear, what isn't clear is: When going back to my website, how do I confirm if the app was installed or not? and do I even need to do that?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind Gerardo, the confusion was due to the old code I was looking at. There's no _big reason_ (there are smaller ones) of why one should authenticate and check that Google actually added the app on the given marketplace, i.e. the integration went through.